# What are the rules for namespace search for qualified names?

Tags: c++, namespaces, name-lookup

Can someone explain the behavior I am seeing for namespace search for qualified names in the following example code? See inline comments for the issue.

```
namespace ns1::hw
{

struct A1
{
   enum class E1
   {   
      E1_1,
      E1_2,
   };  
};

};

namespace ns1::ns2::hw
{

struct A2
{
   enum class E1
   {   
      E1_1,
      E1_2,
   };  
};

};

namespace ns1::ns2::ns3::hw
{

struct A3
{
   enum class E1
   {   
      E1_1,
      E1_2,
   };  
};

};

namespace ns1::ns2::ns3::ns4
{

struct A4
{
   int I1 { (int)hw::A3::E1::E1_1 }; // <--- this compiles OK
                                     // seems to search upwards in the parent namespace,
                                     // looking for the relative partially qualified
                                     // name.

   int I2 { (int)hw::A2::E1::E1_1 }; // <--- this doesn't
                                     // doesn't seem to apply the same search algorithm
                                     // beyond the immediate parent namespace.
};

};

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet:

```
   int I1 { (int)hw::A3::E1::E1_1 }; // <--- this compiles OK
                                     // seems to search upwards in the parent namespace,
                                     // looking for the relative partially qualified
                                     // name.
```

as you seem to expect, `hw` is looked for in `ns4`. It doesn't exist, so it is looked for in the parent namespace `ns3`. It finds `hw` there, and then it finds the nested names `A3`, then `E1`, and then `E1_1`, and so the name lookup succeeds.

In the second snippet:

```
   int I2 { (int)hw::A2::E1::E1_1 }; // <--- this doesn't
                                     // doesn't seem to apply the same search algorithm
                                     // beyond the immediate parent namespace.
```

actually the same rules are applied. `hw` is looked for in `ns4`. It doesn't exist, so it's looked for in `ns3`. It's found there, but *then* it fails to find the nested name `A2`.

Now name lookup will only go upwards in a namespace hierarchy. It will go up as many levels as needed to find a name, but if it ever finds a match inside a namespace level, this process stops. If it then later finds a missing nested name, it won't go in reverse and continue looking upwards in the namespace hierarchy, it's just a hard error instead.

In this case, if there was no `hw` in `ns3`, then the lookup would have gone up to the parent namespace `ns2`, and then the nested names `A2`, `E1`, and `E1_1` would have been found successfully.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting it to be more like e.g. how cpp searches for include files. It tries a relative pathname in the entire search space. It won't stop merely because it finds the initial part of the name.

Comment: @Ziffusion Yes, name lookup rules are different. I'm not sure if there's a *fundamental* reason for this, maybe there would be ambiguities caused by such a rule. At the very least, I think it would be quite painful for an implementation.